Is it best practice to make sealed classes that lacks permits clause?
A sealed class restricts which other classes can extend it, typically achieved using the permits clause. However, if a sealed class does not specify any permitted subclasses using the permits clause, it implicitly allows any class within the same compilation unit to extend it. This can lead to unintended inheritance, where classes that should not have been allowed to extend the sealed class can do so at any time.
Given this potential for unintended inheritance:

should developers always include a permits clause when declaring a sealed class to explicitly control the permitted subclasses?
Are there scenarios where omitting the permits clause might be justified or preferable, or is it generally advisable to specify it?


the same way you can have "unintended inheritance", that is, you (unintendedly) write class A extends B, you can have unintended permit, that is, write class B permits A  (an explicit permits is not needed only for classes inside the same compilation unit - and you have full control over it) --- but this is a very opinion-based question :-/

I think not using permits defeats the purpose of the sealed class, this is my opinion. I mostly think this is a opinion based question, though I will not vote to close it. It is an interesting question.

@user85421 – I assume you should translate "unintended" as "unwanted": the original developer does not want others to extend/implement the non-final class/interface. Whether to use the sealed/permits feature might be opinion based, but using the permits clause on a sealed class is not really optional.

The only use case of omitting the permits I can think of is in auto-generating code. It might allow generating the code for a base class before knowing the full set of subclasses without having to re-edit the base class declaration every time subclass is added. Perhaps also slightly more readable diffs in some version control systems if subclasses are added in separate commits.

As you wrote:

A sealed class restricts which other classes can extend it, typically achieved using the permits clause. However, if a sealed class does not specify any permitted subclasses using the permits clause, it implicitly allows any class within the same compilation unit to extend it.

Refer to JLS 8.1.6 where this is specified (go to the end of the chapter).
In Java, the compilation unit is the *.java file (see JLS 7.3). This means that any "unintended inheritance" is impossible when a sealed class does not provide a permits clause – at least if you do not provide access to the source code, because you have to add the code for the extending class into the same source file as the sealed one. But even then that inheritance is not unintended.
But yes, all sealed classes and interfaces should provide a permits clause just to make it explicit which classes are allowed to extend/implement it.
Omitting the permits clause on a sealed class is just an indication of laziness, there is no scenario where it is advisable, justified or preferable.

I think the key point here is (from the langspec):

Explicit and exhaustive control over a class's direct subclasses is useful when the class hierarchy is used to model the kinds of values in a domain, rather than as a mechanism for code inheritance and reuse. The direct subclasses may themselves be declared sealed in order to further control the class hierarchy.

So if you have a limited, specific class hierarchy like for silverware in a restaurant, you may want to limit it to knife, fork, and spoon. This prevents people from adding chopsticks or differentiating between teaspoons and tablespoons. If your whole class hierarchy has implicit knowledge about these possible types of silverware, sealed may be a good idea.
If you're talking about more multi-purpose classes, you'd be too limiting. For example, InputStream is not sealed and you could implement your own input stream that swaps every other letter.
Think of sealed and permits as conveying a meaning, instead of syntax and access control. They specify a consistent domain model and guide the developer.

the (explicit) permits clause is optional and, as I understand, the question is exactly if it should be used or not, even if not needed, that is, when all subclasses are in the same compilation unit.

@user85421 Yes, I've tried to clarify it a bit. My main point was that it's about guidance, not about strictly enforcing something.

The question is explicitly about whether to add  thepermits clause when the class is sealed. What you refer to is whether the feature of sealed classes and interfaces is useful at all and when – a slightly different focus.
